# How to use java 8 Optional to extract Json Object

Tags: lambda, java-8, option-type

I am learning java8 functional programming and I am going through Optional Lambdas.

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object Obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("demoprgmsv1.json"));
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) Obj;
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
array.add(jsonObject.get("params"));
String functionPath = (String) jsonObject.get("function");
String className= functionPath.substring(0,functionPath.lastIndexOf('.'));
String functionName = functionPath.substring(functionPath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1,functionPath.length() - 2);
Object test= Class.forName(className).newInstance();
method1 = test.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(functionName, JSONArray.class).invoke(test,array);
```

This code is to get function name and parameters written in a JSON file and to execute it.
I was trying to change this code in two three lines using Optional lambdas to avoid try catch block.

```
 Object obj=  Optional
                  .ofNullable(parser.parse(new FileReader("DemoProgram.json")))
                  .orElseThrow(FileNotFoundException::new);
```

I tried to rewrite like this. But not getting result.. please advise....

Comment: Please show an attempt, even if it doesn’t compile (in which case show the compilation error too), so we understand what you want.

Comment: I can’t see you have anything to use an `Optional` for in this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to catch these exceptions and wrap them into one, you **don't need** `Optional`.

- `FileReader` already throws `FileNotFoundException` if the file is not found
- `JSONParser` already throws `ParseException` if it faces `IOException`

```
try {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    Object Obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("demoprgmsv1.json"));
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) Obj;
    // ...
} catch (ParseException | FileNotFoundException exception) {
    throw new IOException(exception); // or better a custom exception
}
```

The subsequent calls **can be handled** through the chain of `Optional` calls. As long as there are multiple exception types present, you might want to throw just one custom exception (depends on the preferred design).

```
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) Obj;
JSONArray array = Optional.ofNullable(jsonObject.get("params"))
    // appendElement(..) is same to add(..) + return this
    .map(obj -> new JSONArray().appendElement(obj))
    .orElseGet(JSONArray::new);                                    // an empty array

String className = Optional.ofNullable(jsonObject.get("function"))
    .map(Object::toString)
    .map(f -> f.substring(0, f.lastIndexOf('.')))
    .orElseThrow(ClassNotFoundException::new);                     // a type is up to you
            
String functionName = Optional.of(className)
    .map(f -> f.substring(f.lastIndexOf('.') + 1, f.length() - 2))
    .orElseThrow(NoSuchMethodException::new);                      // a type is up to you

// at this point both className and functionName exist
// you might want to check the emptyness, though
// also, newInstance is deprecated, better use getDeclaredConstructor

Object test = Class.forName(className).newInstance();
Method method = test.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(functionName, JSONArray.class);
Object returnedObject = method.invoke(test,array);
```